# Converting IQueryable of nullable int to int array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying generate an integer array from a `IQueryable` object of nullable `int`. I'm having issues converting the type `int?` to `int`. The query below builds, but errors out when I execute?

```
int[] result =  (from x in query
                where x.SITE_ID == siteId
                select new
                {
                    x.RANK_1,
                    x.RANK_2,
                    x.RANK_3
                }).Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Comment: "From `IQueryable` object of nullable `int`", no you don't, you have a `IQueryable` of an anonymous type with 3 properties named `RANK_1`, `RANK_2`, and `RANK_3`. So ask your question again with the correct workds *"I'm trying generate an integer array from a `IQueryable` of an anonymous type with 3 properties named `RANK_1`, `RANK_2`, and `RANK_3` which are nullable ints. I'm having issues converting the type class that holds the 3 properties to a int. The query below builds, but errors out when I execute?"*

Answer (score 4):

Each item of your result cannot be casted to `int`. You select an anonymous type with three properties for each item of your result set. How is that can be casted to an `int`?

On the other hand, something like this would work:

```
int[] result =  (from x in query
                 where x.SITE_ID == siteId
                 select x.RANK_1 ?? 0).ToArray();
```

However, I am **not** aware of the meaning of `RANK_1`, `RANK_2` and `RANK_3` and what you want to retrieve. By answering this question you could solve your problem based on the above snippet.

Comment: `RANK_1`, `RANK_2`, and `RANK_3` are table columns I am trying to extract out  from `query`, which is a the result of a previous query that returned all table columns.

Comment: It would be more than helpful if you could include a sample of the input you have (show the `query`) and the expected output. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to cast an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type to an `IEnumerable<int>`.

This line:

```
(from x in query
        where x.SITE_ID == siteId
        select new
        {
            x.RANK_1,
            x.RANK_2,
            x.RANK_3
        })
```

creates an IEnumerable of a new type of object, with 3 properties, `RANK_1`, `RANK_2`, and `RANK_3`.  The call to `Cast<int>` attempts to cast this type to `int`, which isn't possible.